# how to read multiple binary file and then convert into CSV file using asynchronously c#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

i wanted to read binary file and then convert into csv file using multiple threads way.

please suggest how to achieve this goal in .net

```
class Record
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
function ReadFullFile(Action<Record> processRecord)
{
    using(var file = new FileStream("whatever.bin"))
    {
        using(var reader = new BinaryReader(file))
        {
            processRecord(new Record
            {
                Id = reader.ReadInt32(),
                Name = reader.ReadString(),
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would you expect a benefit from using multiple threads?

Comment: You can't.  Using Multiple Thread you will get chunks of data and the BinaryReader will fail unless you have entire received data.  And you can't read a file using multiple threads because the file is one stream.

Comment: i wanted to achieve something like this
https://gunnarpeipman.com/write-csv-from-multiple-threads/

Comment: To me that looks like a solution in search of a problem. A simple lock would do to prevent multiple threads writing to the same csv to step on each other's toes. The I/O is going to be the bottleneck here, so it's not like there's going to be performance benefits from writing from multiple threads in parallel.

Comment: @user1149278 note that your example writes the actual file using only a single thread. You could do roughly the same using a thread that reads the file, and put partial results on a concurrent queue that can be consumed by multiple threads, assuming partial results would be meaningfull. Search for producer consumer pattern and you should find tons of articles. But do you have any reason to think you need this?